# Replacing return with dispatch causes an error

Tags: react-redux

Looking at a simple app, I'm trying to understand Redux. 
You can find the app here: [a simple Redux app](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpnr18p539)

The Redux documentation is saying: "The only way to change the state inside the store is to **dispatch an action**"

But the action-creator in this app looks like this:

```
export const selectSong = song => {
  return {
    type: "SONG_SELECTED", 
    payload: song 
  };
};
```

Clearly, the action is not dispatched. It is returned. So, I thought what happens if I change the function so, that it dispatches the action:

```
export const selectSong = song => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SONG_SELECTED", 
    payload: song 
  });
};
```

But this causes the following error:

**Failed to compile
./src/actions/index.js
  Line 4:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef**

Can some one please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Actually action is dispatching here.

The connect function is commonly passed 1 or 2 arguments:

First argument: A function that plucks pieces of state out of Redux and assigns them to props that your React component will use.

Second argument:  A function which binds action creator functions so that you don’t have to write props.dispatch(actionName()) all over the place, you can just write props.actionName()

https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/

Comment: Thanks. But to be honest I still don't understand why should I use return instead of dispatch in that example.

Comment: You can't use dispatch because you are not passing dispatch prop to that function. Action creators should return plain objects. In your case connect automatically wrap the function in a call to dispatch.https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/4-ways-to-dispatch-actions-with-redux

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `dispatch` is not defined anywhere. Redux by itself (no middlewares) expects objects describing actions. The dispatch in your code sample is bound to redux with `react-redux` `connect` higher order function, so you don't need to call `dispatch` explicitly.

The form of dispatching actions, using dispatch explicitly I've only seen when you use a middleware like `redux-thunk`.

[redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk):

> Thunks are the recommended middleware for basic Redux side effects
>   logic, including complex synchronous logic that needs access to the
>   store, and simple async logic like AJAX requests.

This means you can return functions.

And instead of:

```
export const selectSong = song => {
  return {
    type: "SONG_SELECTED", 
    payload: song 
  };
};
```

You can:

```
export const selectSong = song => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { songs } = getState() // You can access state with getState
    dispatch({
      type: "SONG_SELECTED",
      payload: song
    });
  };
};
```

Here's a link to your code sample with redux-thunk:

https://codesandbox.io/s/1pr283o8l

And here another link to 'redux' with similar thunk code:

https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#actionsjs-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

My pleasure, so what's going on here is you have an action creator that is returning an action object and in that action object you have a property of `type` and `payload`.

To be able to turn your action creator into one that can return a function instead of an action object, you need to decide if you are going to install a middleware like `redux-thunk` and bring that into the mix.

It is from that library that we get the `dispatch` and `getState` arguments that we can use to pass a function instead of an action object from our action creators.

Once you have imported and installed `redux-thunk`, I imagine you would have to refactor your action creator like so:

Before:

```
// Action creator
export const selectSong = (song) => {
  // returns an action
  return {
    type: 'SONG_SELECTED',
    payload: song
  };
};
```

After:

```
export const selectSong = (song) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await songsAPI.get("/songs");
  dispatch({ type: "SONG_SELECTED", payload: song });
};
```

Now I don't know if you are fetching a song from an outside API but I wrote the code this way to make the point that this is something you would implement when you want to develop asynchronous action creators which is also the point of using a middleware like `redux-thunk` and refactoring your action creator in this manner because Redux does not do asynchronous requests out of the box.

Notice I am not using `getState` here as an argument because if you are not going to need it, then please don't define it, but if you use VS Code there should be a squiggly line screaming at you that you haven't used the argument or `getState` should be shaded out indicating you have not used it anywhere, that's a clue, its saying leave this out if you are not going to use it.